# Cannot retrieve paper-input value in JS - WHY?

Tags: javascript, html, css, polymer

Literally no idea what is going on here. It worked in one file on my computer and doesn't in another...

Using an `if` statement to decide whether a `div` should be expanded or not, I am using the content of a `paper-input` to be the boolean operator.

The JS issue is that the value of the input is "undefined"

Please help!

```
<paper-input id="searchMe" class="searchMe" name="searchMe" placeholder="Enter your search here..." on-input="inputText">
      <div suffix>
        <paper-icon-button class="clear" id="clearIcon" icon="clear" on-click="clearInput" style="display: none;"></paper-icon-button>
        <paper-icon-button id="searchIcon" class="search" icon="search" on-click="searchClick"></paper-icon-button>
      </div>
</paper-input>
```

**JS**

```
if(this.$.searchMe.value == "") {
   /* expand div */
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<paper-input id="searchMe" class="searchMe" name="searchMe" placeholder="Enter your search here..." on-input="inputText" value="{{search}}">
```

And this

```
if(this.search == "") {
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Frank.
I seem to have gotten it working again by making the code modular (like I should have done in the first place).

Comment: Did my answer work for you, or did you have another way to do it?

Comment: Hey Frank. I managed to get things sorted before you replied to the question, but I'm sure your answer is correct (you are a lot better at this than me). So I'll give you a tick ;-)